# Missing rows when calling a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a consolited google sheet which import data from others google sheets. I made a little script which push this sheet to an Azure Blob. But when I call `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` and get the number of rows that it contains, I don't have the good number of rows and I don't understand why. Sometimes it will have the good number of rows but in most cases it won't.

Some of you have an idea ?

Thanks

EDIT:
My code

```
var pS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ID)
var sheet = pS.getSheetByName(TAB);
var range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log(range.length);
```

This ID Sheet is the ID of the google sheet importing data from others sheets that can be opened and modified by users.

Trigger

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("Run")
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(23)
   .inTimezone("Europe/Paris")
   .everyDays(1)
   .create();
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what code you use and how many rows you are referring to?

Comment: I expect between 8-10k rows. My code only call `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` and Log the range length. I tried to put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` but did not work. And the others sheets that data are imported from can be opened and modified by others persons in the company.

Comment: How do you get the number of rows the script contains? Can you show your code please?

Comment: Did you try to obtain your row number with `sheet.getLastRow()`? If you have a large amount of data, the script can e.g. timeout while obtaining all values. You can go to View->Executions and see how much time the script run takes. Apps Script has quota limits for usage, if you have a free account the maximum script run time is 6 min.

Comment: @ziganotschka Thank you for your answer ! But in all cases I will have to `getDataRange()` ? Because I transform this sheet to a csv and then push it to my cloud storage

Comment: If you are exceeding the maximum script runtime, you might have to get the data in two separate requests

Comment: I understand that but when I get and push the data, sometimes I have less rows than expected in my csv. So if the timeout happens when I get the data, it should not transform it into a csv and push it ?

Comment: I do not know if you have a timeout or not - please verify it through your script executions

Comment: I have 0% error or timeout on my trigger which executes the script in the Gsuite dashboard

Comment: Can you obtain the correct row number  `sheet.getLastRow()` if you call it before defining `range`?  In this case it is likely that `range.length` is being logged while not all range values have been obtained yet (asynchronous operation). Incorporating `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before logging the `range.length` would solve the issue.

Comment: I tried to put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before getting range and just after `pS.getSheetByName(TAB)`. It worked when I test manually the function but it happens that sometimes after settings the trigger, the number of row is not good. Could it be that the sheet is opened and modified by someone when it triggers ?

Comment: You can test it by creating a test copy of the sheet to which only you have access.

Comment: PS: In the code you provided I cannot see any trigger. If you think your problem might be related to the trigger - please provide the additional code / information

Comment: @ziganotschka Sorry for the delay i was on vacation. I edited my post with the trigger.

Comment: so if your function is `function Run(){var pS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ID)
var sheet = pS.getSheetByName(TAB);
var range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Logger.log(range.length);}` and you call it on trigger - it does not work for you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('TAB').getLastRow());
```